# Form.Closing Event

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am working with a way to close the application by asking the following question but it fails to work.

Any help is awesome!

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing


Dim result As Integer
result = MessageBox.Show("Are you want to close", "Exit", 
MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.None)
If (result = DialogResult.No) Then
    e.Cancel = True
Else
    Application.Exit()
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You have some errors in the code here. Anyway, if `MainWindow` is your startup Form, remove the `Application.Exit()` part and in the Project Proerties set `Shut down mode` to `When last form closes`. Otherwise, the message will be presented twice.

Comment: Ok thank you @Jimi that is fixed but now the issue is now that DialogResult.No gives me an error saying 'No' is not a member of 'Boolean?'

Comment: Your code should be: `If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.None) = DialogResult.No Then e.Cancel = True End If`. But, you have someone answering, here. See that code.

Comment: Wow thank you much! @Jimi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Private _handle As Boolean = True
Private Sub MainWindow_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    If _handle = True Then
        e.Cancel = True

        Dim result = MessageBox.Show("Are you want to close?", "Exit", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.None)
        If (result = MessageBoxResult.Yes) Then
            _handle = False
            Environment.Exit(0)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, this question already has an accepted answer but I thought I'd just add another, a one-liner, as it appears the OP is only doing the `MessageBox` check. I don't feel there's any need for a `boolean` or an `Application.Exit()` `Environment.Exit(0)` in a `Closing` event.

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    If Not MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to close?", "Exit", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.None) = MessageBoxResult.Yes Then e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Red squiggles everywhere!

Comment: C'Mon Mary, don't leave me hanging... Explain that comment.

Comment: `If Not MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to close?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.None) = DialogResult.Yes Then e.Cancel = True`

Comment: Yes that was my answer. Do you want to debate it?

Comment: No, it was not your answer. Your answer does not compile. The devil is in the details.

Comment: Then your compiler is broke ;-) I only give code that I've tested personally with `Option Strict On`. Wait I'll check again in-case it was a `too many beers night`....

Comment: So sorry, I was in a Windows Form project when I tested the code. Didn't realize it was so different in wpf. Will delete comments in a bit.

Comment: Haha, no need to delete. Give me an "upvote" and I'll promise never to look back and re-read for a "chuckle".... ;-)

Comment: Done! :-)  Glad you forgave me.

Comment: 99.9% forgiven, I'll sleep on the remaining 0.1% ;-)